# Prestashop Object model returning null value

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, object-model

Hello everyone can someone help me on this, i am trying to use Prestashop Objectmodel class for Adding, Deliting, Updating and Viewing Data from database, i have achieved retrieving data and displaying it on backoffice Form while clicking Edit button / deliting it from backoffice by clicking Delete option but stuck on saving or Updating it,  here is my codes

Class file

```html
<?php

class TestiBlock extends ObjectModel
{
 public $id_blocktesti;
 public $id_lang;
 public $id_shop;
 public $testi;
 public $image;
 public $name;
 public $rank;

/**
  * @see ObjectModel::$definition
  */
 public static $definition = array(
  'table' => 'blocktesti',
  'primary' => 'id_blocktesti',
  'multilang' => true,
  'fields' => array(
    'id_lang' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_NOTHING),
    'id_shop' =>array('type' => self::TYPE_NOTHING),
    'testi' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML),
    'image' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
    'name' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
    'rank' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
  )
 );
}
```

here is my code for rendering Form

```html
protected function renderForm()
 {
  $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

  $fields_form = array( 
   'tinymce' => true,
   'legend' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('New Testimonial'),
    'image' => '../img/admin/tab-categories.gif',
   ),
   
   'input' => array(
    array(
      'type' => 'hidden',
      'name' => 'id_blocktesti',
       ),
    array(
      'type' => 'file',
      'label' => $this->l('Profile Picture'),
      'name' => 'image',
      'required' => false,
      'hint' => $this->l('Upload a image from your computer.').' (.gif, .jpg, .jpeg '.$this->l('or').' .png)'
     ),
    array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => $this->l('Person\'s Name'),
      'required' => false,
      'name' => 'name',
      'hint' => $this->l('Name of The Person made testimony.')
     ),
    array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => $this->l('Designation or Rank'),
      'required' => false,
      'name' => 'rank',
      'hint' => $this->l('Degignation, Rank or Job Title of person.')
    ),
    array(
      'type' => 'textarea',
      'label' => $this->l('Testimonial'),
      'required' => false,
      'lang' => false,
      'name' => 'testi',
      'cols' => 40,
      'rows' => 10,
      'class' => 'rte',
      'autoload_rte' => true,
      ),
   ),
   
   'submit' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
   ),
   'buttons' => array(
    array(
     'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
     'title' => $this->l('Back to list'),
     'icon' => 'process-icon-back'
    )
   )
  );

  if (Shop::isFeatureActive() && Tools::getValue('id_blocktesti') == false)
  {
   $fields_form['input'][] = array(
    'type' => 'shop',
    'label' => $this->l('Testimonial association'),
    'name' => 'checkBoxShopAsso_theme'
   );
  }


  $helper = new HelperForm();
  $helper->module = $this;
  $helper->name_controller = 'blocktesti';
  $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
  $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
  foreach (Language::getLanguages(false) as $lang)
   $helper->languages[] = array(
    'id_lang' => $lang['id_lang'],
    'iso_code' => $lang['iso_code'],
    'name' => $lang['name'],
    'is_default' => ($default_lang == $lang['id_lang'] ? 1 : 0)
   );

  $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
  $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
  $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;
  $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;
  $helper->title = $this->displayName;
  $helper->submit_action = 'saveblocktesti';

  $helper->fields_value = $this->getFormValues();

  return $helper->generateForm(array(array('form' => $fields_form)));
 }
```

and here is code for processing it

```html
public function getContent() 
 {
  $id_info = (int)Tools::getValue('id_blocktesti');

  if (Tools::isSubmit('saveblocktesti'))
  {
   $info = new TestiBlock((int)$id_info);
   $info->save();
   
   Tools::redirectAdmin(AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'));
  }
  elseif (Tools::isSubmit('updateblocktesti') || Tools::isSubmit('addblocktesti'))
  {
   $this->html .= $this->renderForm();
   return $this->html;
  }
  else if (Tools::isSubmit('deleteblocktesti'))
  {
   $info = new TestiBlock((int)$id_info);
   $info->delete();
   
   Tools::redirectAdmin(AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'));
  }
  else
  {
   $this->html .= $this->renderList();
   return $this->html;
  }

 }
```

and here is my db structure:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_blocktesti` (
  `id_blocktesti` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_lang` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_shop` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `testi` text NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rank` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_blocktesti`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_blocktesti_lang` (
  `id_blocktesti` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_shop` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_lang` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_shop`,`id_lang`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS Note i am using blockcmsinfo for above project.